# How does scala Set de-dupe when class doesn't implement contains?

Tags: scala

Let's assume I have a generic class `Moo` which doesn't implement the `contains` method. If I try to add 5 instances of this class to a scala `MutableSet`, how does it know how to dedupe?

i.e., If I create a `Set(moo1, moo2, moo3, moo4, moo5)` what algorithm does Scala use to remove duplicates?

Comment: It's not the contained class that implements `contains`, it's the collection itself. It wouldn't make sense for every single type to have a `contains` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say `Set(moo1, moo2, moo3, moo4, moo5)` it will create a `HashSet` of `Moo` objects.  In order to determine duplicates, it hashes each element by calling its `hashCode` function.  It may also need to call its `equals` function in case of hash collisions.

So if this is `Moo`:

```
class Moo(val n: Int) {
  override def hashCode() = {
    println(s"hashing: $n")
    n
  }

  override def equals(o: Any) = {
    println(s"checking equality: $this =?= $o")
    o match {
      case m: Moo => n == m.n
      case _ => false
    }
  }

  override def toString() = s"Moo($n)"
}
```

Then calling `Set.apply` looks like this:

```
val moos = Set(new Moo(1), new Moo(2), new Moo(3), new Moo(4), new Moo(3), new Moo(1), new Moo(2))
// checking equality: Moo(2) =?= Moo(1)
// checking equality: Moo(3) =?= Moo(1)
// checking equality: Moo(3) =?= Moo(2)
// checking equality: Moo(4) =?= Moo(1)
// checking equality: Moo(4) =?= Moo(2)
// checking equality: Moo(4) =?= Moo(3)
// checking equality: Moo(5) =?= Moo(1)
// checking equality: Moo(5) =?= Moo(2)
// checking equality: Moo(5) =?= Moo(3)
// checking equality: Moo(5) =?= Moo(4)
// hashing: 1
// hashing: 2
// hashing: 3
// hashing: 4
// hashing: 5
// hashing: 1
// checking equality: Moo(1) =?= Moo(1)
// hashing: 2
// checking equality: Moo(2) =?= Moo(2)
// moos: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Moo] = Set(Moo(5), Moo(1), Moo(2), Moo(3), Moo(4))
```

You can see that for each element added, it check to see if it is "equal" to any previous element; it does this for the first 4 elements because the `Set.apply` factory method has special classes for 1-, 2-, 3-, and 4-element classes.  After 4, it resorts to a normal `HashSet`, so it has to hash all of the elements.  For each subsequent element, it hashes, and then checks equality against any existing elements that have the same hash code.

If you define `Moo` as a `case class`, then you don't have to define `hashCode` or `equals`: the compiler will do it for you.

Comment: Wow. That was a lot more thorough than I had expected. Do all classes in scala inherit the equals and hashCode method like they do in Java? I love the above explanation for when the classes have the hashCode and equality method, but was just curious if it defaults to the same behavior as Java in the absence of their definition.

Comment: Yes, every scala object has a `hashCode` and `equals` defined by default in the same way that java does.  This is true because very scala object *is* a java object.  The default for, eg, equals is to check reference equality; that's why the `case class` thing is cool: it creates a true equality method.